# Segmentation Fault in Python´s Gensim

Tags: python, linux, segmentation-fault, virtual-machine, word2vec

sometimes half hour of running the following script I get a Segmentantion Fault error:
2016-02-09 21:01:21,256 : INFO : PROGRESS: at sentence #9130000, processed 201000982 words, keeping 85047862 word types
Segmentation fault

I´m using Mint on a a VM (VMware workstation 12.0.1) using the word2vec version of gensim-0.12.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg  (Python 2.7.6)

## coding: utf-8

## In[1]:

import os, nltk
import io
import gensim, logging
import nltk

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

## In[2]:

class MySentences(object):

```
def __init__(self, dirname, encoding='iso-8859-1'):
    self.dirname = dirname
    self.encoding = encoding #added encoding parameter for non utf8 texts

def __iter__(self):
    for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):
        sub_dir = os.path.join(self.dirname, fname)
        for fname in os.listdir(sub_dir):
            text_file = os.path.join(sub_dir, fname)
            for line in io.open(text_file, encoding=self.encoding):
                yield nltk.word_tokenize(line, language='english') #you can change tokenizer
```

## In[3]:

sentences = MySentences('/home/arie/extracted')

## In[ ]:

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences)

I just saw the memory monitor and it looks it will crash again any time:

Every 5,0s: free -m                                     Tue Mar 15 19:55:36 2016

```
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
```

Mem:          9837       7735       2102         15        141       1232
-/+ buffers/cache:       6360       3476
Swap:         2044          0       2044

Every 5,0s: free -m                                     Tue Mar 15 19:59:06 2016

```
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
```

Mem:          9837       8563       1274         14          1        108
-/+ buffers/cache:       8453       1384
Swap:         2044         12       2032

Comment: question formatting is a bit off. Can you tell what is the size of memory of your machine, and what is the approx. vocabulary size of your corpus?

Comment: Memory allocated to VR Mint is 9.9 GB (host is 16 GB windows 7) Corpus is a Wikipidia dump (44.717 items, totalling 3,4 GB) extracted with WikiExtractor.  Sorry about the formatting...